# isort always reformats imports even when the char lenght limit is not reached

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, isort

I am using GitHub Actions to ensure the correct formatting of my Python files, specifically by running the following job in my workflow YAML file:

```yaml
command: isort --line-length 120 --profile black --check .
```

Simultaneously, I want to leverage VSCode's capability to automatically reformat .py files upon saving. My current settings.json setup for VSCode includes the following:

```json
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "[python]": {
      "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
      }
    },
    "isort.args": ["--line-length", "120", "--profile", "black"]
}
```

When I have Python files with imports like:

```py
import pandas as pd 
from tableau_api_lib.utils.querying import get_datasources_dataframe, get_workbooks_dataframe
```

The imports are reformatted upon saving into:

```py
import pandas as pd 
from tableau_api_lib.utils.querying import (
    get_datasources_dataframe,
    get_workbooks_dataframe,
)
```

I intend to keep the second import on one line unless the 120-character threshold is breached. How can I achieve this desired behavior with my current VSCode and isort configuration?

Note:

1. For this project I am using poetry for managing my library dependencies. Inside of the venv of my project - isort is added to the `pyproject.toml` file - running the following command:

   ```bash
   isort --line-length 120 --profile black .
   ```

   Gives me the wanted sorting
2. I have explored the [Force Grid Wrap](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html#force-grid-wrap) solution which does not match with my requirements. My goal is to allow reformatting only when the line length exceeds a certain threshold (in this case, 120 characters).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom profile in your `pyproject.toml` file.

```ini
[tool.isort]
line_length = 120
multi_line_output = 3
include_trailing_comma = true
force_grid_wrap = 0
use_parentheses = true
ensure_newline_before_comments = true
```

Then, you can remove the `isort.args` setting in `setting.json` and set as the following cdoes:

```json
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the lines mentioned above inside `pyproject.toml`. Then, updated the lock file with `poetry lock --no-update` and installed the depencies from lock file with `poetry install`. I edited the `settings.json` file as suggested (I keep black formatter). I reloaded vscode window, then also restarted it. Still, I get the same unwanted behavior. Still thank you, for your suggestion.